# How can I count ids in splunk logs in one line with regex

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have log like:
Segment 5bbdf7b8bbdd3c685a2110bf : UserMap is [512205885, 512112460, 512369891, 512316786, 58587803, 506882296]

Segment 5bbdf7b8bbdd3c685a2110bf : UserMap is [514348564, 506722271, 513844106, 513725157]
Segment 5bbdfd69bbdd3c685a21129b : UserMap is [502062935]

I want the stats where I can see number of ids in userMap with respect to the segment. like:

5bbdf7b8bbdd3c685a2110bf - 6

5bbdf7b8bbdd3c685a2110bf - 4

5bbdfd69bbdd3c685a21129b - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do it all with regex, but this search should get you goingin the right direction.

```
<your base search> | rex "Segment (?<Segment>[^:]+)" 
| rex max_match=0 "UserMap is \[(?<id>\d+)" 
| idCount=mvcount(id) | table Segment idCount
```